# ZeroMQ/NanoMsg pub/sub vs multicast

Tags: zeromq, nanomsg, opendds, aeron

I want to implement data distribution application using zeromq or nanomsg or aeron.net or OpenDDS or OpenMAMA, I am little confused , which one is suitable as my requirement is to support 500 to 1000 users and each user can subscribe for atleast 100 topics

this can be handled by using pub/sub pattern or I have to use UDP multicast ?

Also I need to deploy this application on Amazon EC2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You mix apples with oranges :

> "Can <sub>*( this )*</sub> be handled by using pub/sub pattern **or** <sub>*( do )*</sub> I have to use UDP multicast?"

The **`PUB/SUB`** Scalable Formal Communication Pattern tells how the agents behave each to the other.

Whereas,
the UDP multicast tells what technical transport class could be preferred to be used, i.e. either of **`{ pgm:// | epgm:// }`** from those of all the technically available ones
 `{ inproc:// | ipc:// | tcp:// | pgm:// | epgm:// | vmci:// }`

Finalle,
the **`PUB/SUB`** can work over `{ pgm:// | epgm:// }`, so the "**or**"-choice constructor is principally not an adequate one.

---

### Back to Scaling :

Neither ZeroMQ nor nanomsg ( as of implementations available in 2018-Q1 ) will have issues with the `PUB/SUB` mechanics over ~ 1000 users x 100+ topics.

For details, one may read wonderfull Martin Sustrik's technical details how and why topic-filters work in either of these platforms. He, being a father of both these signalling / messaging systems, one could hardly ask a better or more insightfull person on this subject and its limits.

Having expressed your prior exposure to FinTech / FIX-Protocol / Trading platforms, you ought have experience enough to decide further on principal issues.

---

### Also I need to deploy this application on Amazon EC2 :

Easy. Go get it done. If in problems, re-read platform documentation and ask the service provider first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry could not elaborate my question. actually I wanted to know that pub/sub sockets provided by zeormq or nanomsg can handle this load using tcp protocol or I have to use pgm/epgm. In using pgm/epgm I see difficulty of network management